# Collection type of choices can't pass validation

Tags: symfony4

I created a form with choice collection type.

```php
$builder->add('roles', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'    => ChoiceType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'choices'  => ['Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'User' => 'ROLE_USER'],
                    'label'    => false,
                ],
            ])
```

*roles* field is defined in user's entity as follows:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="json")
*/
private $roles = [];
```

Then in user's entity class I added following method:

```
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata) {
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('roles', new Assert\Choice(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER']));
}
```

Each time when I try to submit form I get validation error: "The value you selected is not a valid choice."

[screenshot of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Vob.jpg)

What is weird that error message is shown above all fields, which means that error is not related to any available fields.

Name of the select with roles is `user[roles][0]` which was created automatically.
If I turn off validation all data are saved correctly to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assert\Choice expect that value of field "role" would be scalar type but roles is collection. To validate collection with Assert\Choice you need do this

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('roles', new Assert\All([
    'constraints' => [
         new Assert\Choice(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
    ],
]));
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use Assert\All too, but didn't now that I need to use 'constraints' key.